# How to create an addition function using a while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I need to figure out how to print all of the inputs along with the total when I select report type "A". When I select report type "T" it gives only the total as planned. If I select report type "A" it gives me the input "Q" plus the sum of all of the inputs.

```
def addition_function():
  sum = 0

while True:
    add = input("Enter a number to add or \"Q\" to quit:")
    if add.isdigit() == True:
        sum = sum + int(add)
    elif add.lower() == "q":
        rep_type = input("Enter report type (A/T):")
        if rep_type.lower() == "a":
            return print(add,sum)
            break
        elif rep_type.lower() == "t":
            return print("Total =",sum)
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid input.")
    else:
        print("Invalid input.")

addition_function()
```

Comment: You should add a language tag to this.

Comment: The code didn't copy and paste that well.

Comment: That matters less.  I'd tag this for you if I knew what language it is.  It will help your question get found.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but the `return` statements here do nothing. (Since you're not inside a function. If you were, they would end the function's execution, which it looks like you wouldn't want.)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I removed the returns but I still can't figure out how to print all of the inputs that are entered with the total.

Comment: With report "A", I need it to print this:

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list to keep track of all the numbers entered by the user and print it when user inputs 'A' and use that variable to print them:

```
def addition_function():
    sum = 0
    nums_entered = []

    while True:
        add = input("Enter a number to add or \"Q\" to quit:")
        if add.isdigit() == True:
            nums_entered.append(add)
            sum = sum + int(add)
        elif add.lower() == "q":
            rep_type = input("Enter report type (A/T):")
            if rep_type.lower() == "a":
                return print(nums_entered,sum)
            elif rep_type.lower() == "t":
                return print("Total =",sum)
            else:
                print("Invalid input.")
        else:
            print("Invalid input.")

addition_function()
```